# Docker - Nginx autoreload on config file changes

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have an nginx container, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19.2

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /etc/nginx/conf.d

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/conf.d/my-site/my-domain.generic.conf \
  && ln -s /etc/nginx/conf.d/my-site/my-domain.conf

COPY ./certs/* /etc/ssl/
```

and I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  my-site_nginx:
    container_name: my-site_nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      network: host
    image: my-site_nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443' # SSL
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
```

I am looking for a way to have the nginx service inside the container to autoreload  (`nginx -s reload`) when I change anything inside the `conf.d` folder as well as in the `nginx.conf` file that's located at the same level with the `conf.d` folder.

The closest thing I've found was this tutorial here: https://cyral.com/blog/how-to-auto-reload-nginx/
But I had to adapt the paths a bit, I don't know what `openresty` is, I suppose it's a custom image or something? (Docker noob here)... Anyway, I've tried the following from that link:

Created the docker-entrypoint.sh and nginxReloader.sh files:

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
###########

sh -c "nginxReloader.sh &"
exec "$@"
```

nginxReloader.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
###########

while true
do
  inotifywait --exclude .swp -e create -e modify -e delete -e move /etc/nginx/conf.d
  nginx -t
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Detected Nginx Configuration Change"
    echo "Executing: nginx -s reload"
    nginx -s reload
  fi
done
```

And added this to Dockerfile:

```
# [...]

COPY ./nginxReloader.sh /usr/local/bin/nginxReloader.sh
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/nginxReloader.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install inotify-tools -y

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
# CMD ["/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty", "-g", "daemon off;"] (don't know what this would do, but I wouldn't know what to replace `openresty` with in my case, so I omitted this line from the tutorial at the link I provided)
```

But when trying to `docker-compose up --build` it either errored with `No such file or directory` for line `exec "$@"` in the `nginxReloader.sh` file OR I got `nginx exited with code 0` when doing `docker-compose up` (of course, I tried different things between those errors, but can't remember exactly what).

Also, I've tried to point the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile directly to nginxReloader.sh (`ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/nginxReloader.sh" ]`) but then when trying docker-compose up I only get 2 lines of output:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

and nginx never starts (I suppose it's because of that `while true` loop).

Also, if I completely remove the ENTRPOINT line in Dockerfile, when running `docker-compose up` I still get the following output:

```
my-site_nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
my-site_nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
my-site_nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
my-site_nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
my-site_nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
my-site_nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

like Docker is somehow aware of that file being in the folder, on the same level with the Dockerfile... No errors, but changing a config still doesn't trigger `nginx -s reload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not running the original entrypoint when you override it with your new entrypoint, so `nginx` will not start. Change

### docker-entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
###########

sh -c "nginxReloader.sh &"
exec "$@"
```

to

### docker-entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
###########

sh -c "nginxReloader.sh &"
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer by @TarunLalwani is missing changes to the Dockerfile that are also required.

I wasn't able to edit their answer, so here is the updated solution that is verified to work, including some additional clarifications.

..................

There are 2 issues:

First, you are not running the original entrypoint when you override it with your new entrypoint. Change

### docker-entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
###########

sh -c "nginxReloader.sh &"
exec "$@"
```

to

### docker-entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
###########

sh -c "nginxReloader.sh &"

# See changes to Dockerfile next for more details, but
# you aren't including `CMD` in your Dockerfile. So 
# forwarding the arguments ("$@") won't include "nginx", 
# which is what the default nginx /docker-entrypoint.sh
# will look for before setting up the service.
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Second, as stated above, you also need to include `CMD` in your Dockerfile, or you'll still get `nginx exited with code 0`.  Add:

### Dockerfile

```
...

# same as before
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

# But include this, which is the same command as in the 
# default nginx Dockerfile:
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

The line in the tutorial that you linked to but commented out in your Dockerfile version was:

`CMD ["/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

You're not using the openresty version of nginx, so you're just using "nginx". And it's a registered command so you don't need to use the path to the bin file like he's doing for openresty.